# Power off mini-icon not showing in actions menu

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I cannot see the power off mini-icon in the top right screen (actions menu) in GNOME (Xorg and Wayland):

[image: Problem]

But in desktop PCs seems to appear propperly (image taken from a website):

[image: Good (PC)]

How can I show this icon in my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/# and search for "power off" or "shutdown". Find the gnome-shell extension that works for you.

Comment: I didn't find anything in GNOME extensions, only addons that create a new menu for shutdown options.

Comment: That's what you asked for, no? I saw plenty of candidates.

Comment: No, I dont want a new menu. I just want to make the current actions menu to display the small power off icon.

Comment: What's the point of having a small power off icon if it doesn't do anything?

Comment: Yeah, but it's cool.

Comment: It may help new users to understand where things are.

Comment: Can't just put up an empty power off icon.